# How do you print an array based on another arrays position?

Tags: arrays, powershell, compare, match

I have 2 arrays. If Joe Root is entered and exists, how can I print that array and the age "67" from the other array?

```
$myarr = ("John Morales", "Joe Root", "Peter Barkley" )
$myarr1 = (45, 67, 31)
$name = read-host "Enter your name" 

if ($myarr -contains $name)
{
     write-host "Name            Age"
     write-host "--------        ---"
     "{0,-11} {1,10}" -f "
 }
```

Comment: `(45, 67, 31)[("John Morales", "Joe Root", "Peter Barkley").IndexOf('Joe Root')]`, but  note that `.IndexOf` is case-sensitive.

Comment: In short: Use `$array.IndexOf()` for case-_sensitive_ string or non-string lookups, and `[Array]::FindIndex($array, [Predicate[object]] { 'foo' -eq $args[0] })` for case-_insensitive_ lookups. See the linked duplicate for details.

Comment: You should really look into [hash tables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_hash_tables?view=powershell-7.2)